# snipmate: comments in snippet

Tags: vim, snipmate

How to add a comment in a snippet of the form

```
snippet function
        /*
         * === FUNCTION =====================================
         *        Name: ${1:name}
         * Description: ${2:description}
         * ==================================================
         */
         ${3:void} $1(${4:args}) {
         ${5}
         }
```

The latter seems not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initial edit missed tabstop `${4}`, that's why the snippet navigation stops after the `void`. (I guess that's what you mean by "the latter seems not to work"; please try to be more precise in the future.)

---

The following works for me in Vim 7.4.264, using my custom [snipMate fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/snipMate.vim). I've replaced tab characters with `\t`, because SO doesn't show then right:

```
snippet function
\t/*
\t * === FUNCTION =====================================
\t *        Name: ${1:name}
\t * Description: ${2:description}
\t * ==================================================
\t */
\t${3:void} $1(${4:args}) {
\t${5}
\t}
```

If your "freeze" is an endless loop inside Vimscript, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> should abort it. You can then retry with verbose logging: Capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for suspect commands. You should be able to see the endless loop, and hopefully get ideas how to fix them. Unfortunately, the original snipMate isn't maintained any more, but some forks are alive. You may check out those; they might work better.

Comment: Sorry, that was a misprint. It still does not work: When using it in vim, vim freezes

Comment: Hm, works for me. I've added some more troubleshooting info, hopefully that'll get you started in the right direction.

Comment: the tabs were replaced by spaces, that was the reason why it didn't work. Thank you for your help!